# SplashScreen c анимацией и ProgressBar

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-animation

Пытаюсь сделать `SplashScreen`, чтобы сначала у меня выполнялась анимация появления `TextView` с `ImageView`, а затем, в конце, появился `ProgressBar`. Но у меня, при запуске приложения, `ProgressBar` появляется сразу же, до того, как выполнится анимация.

---

*P.S. Пытался сделать через потоки, в итоге - анимации нет, но зато одновременно появляются `TextView`, `ImageView` и `ProgressBar`.*

*Реализация с потоком:*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tvhead;
    ImageView splash;
    Animation fromtop;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        splash = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splash_view);
        tvhead = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHead);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doWork();
                startApp();
                finish();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void doWork(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            fromtop = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.splash_view);
            splash.setAnimation(fromtop);
            tvhead.setAnimation(fromtop);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void startApp(){
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

*Реализация без потока:*

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // This method will be executed once the timer is over
            // Start your app main activity
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

            // close this activity
            finish();
        }
    }, 4000);
```

---

Как сделать так, чтобы сначала у меня выполнялась анимация появления `TextView` и `ImageView`, а затем уже `ProgressBar` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fromtop.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
                  startActivity(i);

                  finish();
              }
        }, 4000);
    }
}

splash.setAnimation(fromtop);
tvhead.setAnimation(fromtop);
```

Comment: Это можно использовать без потока ?

Comment: да тут ничего крутого, чтобы поток давать)

Comment: но Handler нужно создавать ?

Comment: зачем?, если сначала дождёмся конца анимации, а потом просто запускаем intent

Comment: я просто не понимаю, как запустить progressbar после окончания анимации ?

Comment: обновил свой ответ

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87433/discussion-between-programmer-and-ifr0z).